# How do I Instantiate a class within a class in .php

Tags: php, oop, class

I'm new to OOP and I can't figure out why this isn't working.  Is it not ok to instantiate a class with in a class.  I've tried this with included file with in the method and it didn't make a change.

```
include('Activate.php');

class First {
    function __construct() {
    $this->activate();
    }       
    private function activate() {
    $go = new Activate('Approved');
    }
}

$run = new First();
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating `First` (do you have `$first = new First();` later on?)

Comment: YES.. I'll edit.  I initiate the class at the end of the document.

Comment: is `include` working? It can return false. Do you mean to have `$this->go = new Activate(...)`? You create a new `Activate` and then it is discarded because the `activate()` function finishes. I cannot tell if this is intentional.

Comment: I created activate() on the fly.  I'm trying to turn on the plugin by invoking the Activate class.  Does this make better sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured out my issue.  My code had two errors.  One that being my method was set to private and secondly I had an error in my `$parms` that I was sending to the class.

```
include('Activate.php');

class First {
    function __construct() {
    $this->activate();
    }       
    private function activate() {
    $go = new Activate('Approved');
    }
}

$run = new First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that you want to access `$go`? because, if that is the case, you need to change the scope of it.

As you see, `$go` in this method is only available inside `activate()`:

```
private function activate() {
    $go = new Activate('Approved');
}
```

to make it reachable from other location within the class, you would need to declare it outside `activate()`:

```
private $go = null;
```

you call `$go` by using `$this`:

```
private function activate() {
    $this->go = new Activate('Approved');
}
```

After that, if you want to access go from outside class, you would need to create wrapper:

```
public function getGo(){
   return $this->go;
}
```

Hope this helped. Also, you can read the [documentation about OOP in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Comment: Here's the big picture.  I'm running a class at run time.  Inside the class I detect weather or not the program was registered.  If it has been registered then I need to instantiate another class. The names of the method I threw together on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can access your private method with the help of create another public function in the same class and call the private function in the public method or function. Now you can call your private function with the help of **$run** instance.

**For example:**

class Cars{

```
function getting(){
    echo ("Hello World");   
}

private function getting2(){
    echo ("Hello World Againg");
}

public function getting3(){
    $this->getting2();
}
```

}

$class_object=new Cars;

print($class_object->getting3());

---

**Your output screen like the below image.**

[image]

---